# AngularJS, ui.grid: How can I get the selected row's data

Tags: angularjs, grid, ui-grid

I'm new to angular, and I can't get any proper answer for that :( Please help

I need to get the selected row's data, then pass it to another page.

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you provide some of your code? Are you using `ng-repeat` to fill the rows with data?

Comment: I posted a general answer, please add your code to help you with the issue

Answer (score 0):

When configuring `gridOptions` you can register to ui-grid's API and get the selected rows:

**Controller**

```
private getGridOptions() {
    return {
        onRegisterApi: (gridApi: uiGrid.IGridApi) => {
            this.selectedRows = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
                }
            };
          }
```

More on interaction with ui-grid's API - http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions